# Saving & Restoring Connections with XIFF

Tags: connection, xmpp, xiff

I'm modifying a piece of JavaScript code that uses XMPP + XIFF flash object to communication with MSN/Yahoo/GTalk via Jabber.

The requirement of the web site is to enable page refreshes.

However, the problem is the current implementation of XIFF does not allow saving and restoring of connection, but requires a new login every time, which is time consuming.

I wasn't able to find any reference to such a solution.

Does anyone know if:

1. This is at all possible with the XIFF open source code?
2. Any reference to such solution - might consider JavaScript solution as well.

Thank you very much!

Ofer Bar

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible.  Standard work-arounds are to either have a separate window, or some form of IFRAME which acts as such.